# How to appear the chapter name in the header of an odd page if the chapter does not contain section

Tags: header-footer

I have the following code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
 left=1in, 
 right=1in, 
 top=1.25in, 
 bottom=1.25in,
 headsep=30pt,
 heightrounded
 ]{geometry}
 \usepackage[x11names, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 %==============================================================
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%==============================================================
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
 \usepackage{lipsum}

  \begin{document}

  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \thispagestyle{plain}
  \tableofcontents
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
  \thispagestyle{plain}

  \newpage

  \pagenumbering{arabic}

 \chapter{Preliminaries}
  \section{Basics}
   \lipsum[1-15]

  \chapter{$C3$-Modules}
   \lipsum[1-30]

    \end{document}
```

As you see, chapter 3 has no sections. I need **Chapter 3. $C3$-Modules** appears in the header of every page of the chapter, not only in the even pages. I need this behaviour for those chapters which do not contain sections.

Comment: Thanks @cabohah 
This is a good solution

Answer (score 0):

You can test for an empty `\rightmark` and use `\leftmark` in this case (I've removed several packages not related to the problem):

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% should also not be needed from LaTeX 2018-04-01
\usepackage[
 left=1in, 
 right=1in, 
 top=1.25in, 
 bottom=1.25in,
 headsep=30pt,
 heightrounded
 ]{geometry}
 %==============================================================
\usepackage{scrextend}% provides \Ifstr (and others)
\providecommand\Ifstr{\ifstr}% for historic LaTeX installations only.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\nouppercase{\Ifstr{\rightmark}{}{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%==============================================================
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage% not needed in this case, but needed, e.g. if there is a
                % title before the following lines.
\pagenumbering{roman}
\thispagestyle{plain}% not needed, because default for chapters and therefore table of contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents

\newpage% should \cleardoublepage, or use \mainmatter instead of \pagenumbering

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\section{Basics}
\lipsum[1-15]

\chapter{$C3$-Modules}
\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Note: You should use `\cleardoublepage` instead of `\newpage` before `\pagenumbering`. Otherwise it could happen, that two odd pages are following each other, which is problematic, when printing the document. With `book` I recommend to use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` instead of `\pagenumbering`, because these automatically use `\cleardoublepage`, when needed.

Also note, that adding `\addcontentsline` *after* `\tableofcontents` would use the last page of the table of contents instead of the first one as reference in the table of contents. Best would be to use package `tocbibind` to add such entries (or use a class, that already supports such entries).

Comment: Excuse me, can you show me how to use `\frontmatter` and `mainmatter` ? Where to put these lines ?

Comment: I get an error when I run this code. Texmaker says that `\Ifstr` is undefined control sequence. However, egreg's solution (the accepted answer in the link you posted in the comment) worked for me.

Comment: It is irrelevant what Texmaker says. Relevant is, what LaTeX says. `\Ifstr` is defined in `scrextend` since version 3.28 (end of 2019). Before it was `\ifstr`. But if you are using a more than 4 years old LaTeX, you should consider an update.

Comment: For using `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` just replace `\pagenumbering{roman}` by `\frontmatter` (and then you can remove the `\cleardoublepage`) and replace `\pagenumbering{arabic}` by `\mainmatter` (and then you can remove the `\newpage`). See a LaTeX introduction for more information.

Comment: Excuse me, how can I update Latex? Is it possible to update or do you mean that I have to remove the old latex and download a new one?. If I downloaded a new version, will the old codes run properly?

Comment: @HusseinEid This is another question and the answer depends on the TeX distribution you are using. With MiKTeX see: [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/277964). There are similar questions for TeX Live depending on Vanilla or Linux package versions.